# RewriteRule changing HTML Image Link

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\w+\ /(.*)\.php(\?.*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .* $0.php

RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^anime/(.*)/?$ anime.php?anime_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

I'm quite new to whole using .htaccess to Rewrite a URL and right now it does what I want with the above code I can go to "localhost/anime/1" and it will display the correct page but the problem is on that page I have the following

```
<img src="../images/anime/<?php echo $animeID; ?>/Cover.jpg" />
```

The Rewrite rule seems to change this and ends up being turned into

```
<img src="../images/anime/1.php/1/Cover.jpg" />
```

I can't work out how to prevent this and its starting to annoy me! I can just go into the images folder and change the anime folder to something else and works fine but I would rather learn how to fix the Rewrite rule.

Thanks for any help! Hopefully I explained my problem well enough.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are in `/anime/1/` you need to get up two levels, so you should use

```
<img src="../../images/anime/<?php echo $animeID; ?>/Cover.jpg" />
```

Or avoid all this mess with dots, and use root relative urls; like so

```
<img src="/images/anime/<?php echo $animeID; ?>/Cover.jpg" />
```

(note the leading slash)

Comment: I had tried these and when view page source they are turned into

    <img src="../../images/anime/1.php/1/Uncensored.jpg">
    <img src="/images/anime/1.php/1/Uncensored.jpg">

Rewrite Rule appears to add 1.php which is messing up the whole url.

Comment: Mod_rewrite doesn't change the html source code!!! Are you sure $animeID contains the correct value?

Comment: Yes I'm sure $animeID contains the correct value, if I change the mod_rewrite to say ^title/(.*)/?$ anime.php?anime_id=$1 [NC,L] then it works just fine my images will load but I don't want /title/1.

I don't understand why mod_rewrite is changing my <?php echo $animeID ?> in my html.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use RecriteCond to ignore your rewrite rules for existing files and directories. 
Replace your code with this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php(?:\?([^\s]+)) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/%2 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^page/(.*?)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^anime/(.+?)/?$ /anime.php?anime_id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .* $0.php [L]
```

Comment: My understanding was indeed that I needed to prevent existing files and directories from being affected but the above code did not work when I try the page anime/1/ instead of anime.php?anime_id=1 I get nothing now.

Comment: Hmm seems to work on Localhost but once I try put it live all pages are blank.